# Setting a field to a date in the future using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to set an input field to a date 365 days from the current date. This field sets the expiration date of a membership purchase. I have this javascript which does not work for some reason.

```
<input type="text" name="ZoneExpiry" id="ExpiryDate" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function setExpiryDate( )
{
var dat=new Date();
dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 45);
var monthname=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun",   "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
var pretty = dat.getDate() + "-" + monthname[dat.getMonth()] + "-" + dat.getFullYear();    
document.getElementById("ExpiryDate").value = pretty;
}
</script>
```

I'm no javascript expert but for some reason this is not setting the input field to the proper value.

Is there a way to fix this javascript or accomplish a similar task using jQuery?

The date format needs to be 01-Jan-2010, so day-month-4digit year.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Define "not setting to the proper value".  Is the wrong field being updated?  Is the field being updated to an incorrect value, or not updated at all?  What does your debugger show the value of `pretty` is on line 5 of your function?

Comment: What I seen when I preview in a web browser is an empty field. The script is not setting the value of the input field. Not sure about the value of pretty. Not great at debugging the javascript. Can you recommend a good debugger?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jQuery:

```
    <input type="text" name="ZoneExpiry" id="ExpiryDate" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.setExpiryDate = function(expirationDay) {
       var dat = new Date(),
           pretty = 0,
           monthname = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun", "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

       dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + expirationDay);

       pretty = dat.getDate() + "-" + monthname[dat.getMonth()] + "-" + dat.getFullYear();

       $(this).val(pretty);
    }

    $('#ExpiryDate').setExpiryDate(365);
    ​</script>
```

Comment: yes, for this function only has to be loaded "ExpiryDate". Can be in '$(document).ready(...)' or like this in the example after "ExpiryDate"

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.  The only thing that seems to be wrong is that you are adding 45 days to the current date rather than 365.

Comment: When I preview the code in my browser, the text field is empty. Nothing shows. The 45 days glitch is my error. Forgot to update that code. Where are you seeing it work? Sorry for basic questions, I'm not that familiar with javascript.

Comment: How are you invoking your Javascript function?  Is there a `onclick` handler somewhere?

Comment: It needs to run on page load. The field will eventually be hidden so the script needs to run automatically? Is that the problem?